# Get date out of year and day of year from a value - Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, user-defined-functions

I have a 6 digit value from which i have to get the date in scala. For eg if the value is  -  119003 then the output should be

```
1=20 century
19=2019 year
003= january 3
```

The output should be 2019/01/03

I have tried ti split the value first and then get the date. But i am not sure how to proceed as i am new to scala

Comment: If January 3rd is `003` then how is December 23rd expressed? Which part of `00` is the month? If `1` means century `20` then `0` means `19`? And the year `1899` cannot be represented?

Comment: it is day of year. Like 365 days. And yes 0 means 19 and 1899 cannot be represented

Comment: Currently i have managed to split the values.
object stringparse {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val datestring= "119039"

    val century = (datestring.slice(0,1))

    val year = (datestring.slice(1,3))

    val dayofyear = (datestring.slice(3,6))

    println(century + "," + year + "," + dayofyear)
    }

Comment: Could you educate your source to use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? The format you got is weird and needlessly complicated to parse.

Comment: ha ha yea. But they had a file which was having it in this format. Will have to talk to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to do the century calculations manually. After that you can let the `java.time` library do all the rest.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val in = "119003"
val cent = in.head.asDigit + 19
val res = LocalDate.parse(cent+in.tail, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyDDD"))
                   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"))
//res: String = 2019/01/03
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` class of Java 1.0 used 1900-based years, so 119 would mean 2019, for example. This use was deprecated already in Java 1.1 more than 20 years ago, so it’s surprising to see it survive into Scala.

When you say *6 digit value*, I take it to be a number (not a string).

The answer by jwvh is correct. My variant would be like (sorry about the Java code, please translate yourself):

```
    int value = 119003;
    int year1900based = value / 1000;
    int dayOfYear = value % 1000;
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofYearDay(year1900based + 1900, dayOfYear);
    System.out.println(date);
```

> 2019-01-03

If you’ve got a string, I would slice it into two parts only, 119 and 003 (not three parts as in your comment). Parse each into an `int` and proceed as above.

If you need `2019/01/03` format in your output, use a `DateTimeFormatter` for that. Inside your program, do keep the `LocalDate`, not a `String`.

Comment: These are some very old files that they want us to handle. Thanks for the answer. :)